# How to align a text on the top of a bubble message

Tags: html, css

I would like to adjust the user name in the message box, just above, just as it is in Messenger, but I don't know how to do that, I don't know about CSS, so could someone help me? I want it to be responsive and equal in the example photo
I want the name as small as it is in Messenger, so would a  tag be enough? And how to put it on top of the chat message box

**Example that I want:**

[image of example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rayQm.jpg)

**Source**

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica;
  display: flex ;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.chat {
  width: 300px;
  border: solid 1px #EEE;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
}

.messages {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.message {
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.yours {
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.yours .message {
  margin-right: 25%;
  background-color: #eee;
  position: relative;
}

.yours .message.last:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -7px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #eee;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}
.yours .message.last:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  background: white;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.mine {
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.mine .message {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 25%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00D0EA 0%, #0085D1 100%);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: relative;
}

.mine .message.last:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -8px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00D0EA 0%, #0085D1 100%);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}

.mine .message.last:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  background: white;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Chat Bubbles - iOS style</h1>
<div class="chat">
  <div class="mine messages">
    <div class="message last">
      Dude
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="yours messages">
    <div><small style="color:red; margin:0; padding:0; ">Username</small></div>
    <div class="message">
      Hey!
    </div>
    <div class="message">
      You there?
    </div>
    <div class="message last">
      Hello, how's it going?
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mine messages">
    <div class="message">
      Great thanks!
    </div> 
    <div class="message last">
      How about you?
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added the <small> tag it looks like it's up there, but how can I make the text lower and more responsive on all devices?

Comment: See my solution down here. If this covers your question, please mark the answer as solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're such a great person

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a `.yours .user` and a `.mine .user` combo css class for the username styling. Also, you don't need the `small` tag. It can just be a `div`. I've added them below.

```css
    body {
      font-family: helvetica;
      display: flex ;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .chat {
      width: 300px;
      border: solid 1px #EEE;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    .messages {
      margin-top: 30px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    .message {
      border-radius: 20px;
      padding: 8px 15px;
      margin-top: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .yours {
      align-items: flex-start;
    }

    .yours .message {
      margin-right: 25%;
      background-color: #eee;
      position: relative;
    }

    .yours .message.last:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: -7px;
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      background: #eee;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    }
    .yours .message.last:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      bottom: 0;
      left: -10px;
      width: 10px;
      height: 20px;
      background: white;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    }

    .mine {
      align-items: flex-end;
    }

    .mine .message {
      color: white;
      margin-left: 25%;
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00D0EA 0%, #0085D1 100%);
      background-attachment: fixed;
      position: relative;
    }

    .mine .message.last:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: -8px;
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00D0EA 0%, #0085D1 100%);
      background-attachment: fixed;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    }

    .mine .message.last:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      bottom: 0;
      right: -10px;
      width: 10px;
      height: 20px;
      background: white;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    }
    
    .yours .user {
      font-size:0.6em;
      color: grey;
      margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    }
    
    .mine .user {
      font-size:0.6em;
      color: grey;
      margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    }
```

```html
    <h1>Chat Bubbles - iOS style</h1>
    <div class="chat">
      <div class="mine messages">
      <div class="user">Me</div>
        <div class="message last">
          Dude
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="yours messages">
        <div class="user">Josh</div>
        <div class="message">
          Hey!
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          You there?
        </div>
        <div class="message last">
          Hello, how's it going?
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mine messages">
      <div class="user">Me</div>
        <div class="message">
          Great thanks!
        </div> 
        <div class="message last">
          How about you?
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I want <3